# PHP issue using sessions

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm new to sessions, and since i need to use a whole bunch of them right now it seemed inevitable to create a problem.

I was told to make a Card game (BlackJack) using only PHP and HTML. So far so good, got the cards and everything in it, start, hit, stand and reset work all fine.

I did this by using forms. A form for start a form for hit and a form for Stand. And by using sessions it reminded all the cards it had and the score.

But the problem came when i started inserting a bet system. I started with a standard bank which is 100

I have an input field in my start form aswell which is where the bet will be placed. And when the user click on the start form it will call this function among some others:

```
// Calculate the bank
function calc_bank() {
   $_SESSION["bet"] = $_POST["bet"];
   $_SESSION["bank"] = 100 - $_SESSION["bet"];
}
```

And this one works as well, it will echo out 95 when the user clicks start (minimal bet is 5). And when the user clicks hit, it will go to the hit form, remember all sessions and show 95 as well, same with stand.

And here is my problem, when say, i bust by pressing hit and getting 23 points. Nothing happens to the $_SESSION["bank"] and the bet will stay 95. But when the user changes his next bet to say 20. And click start it will calculate the bank again, and as you can guess, it will take the standard 100 - 20 and make the SESSION 80, while it should've been 75.

I really hope I explained my problem clearly enough for you guys, If not please tell me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time you call your function, the $_SESSION["bank"] is equal to 100 minus the bet.

Try this

```
function calc_bank() {
   if (!isset($_SESSION["bank"])){$_SESSION["bank"]=100;}
   $_SESSION["bet"] = $_POST["bet"];
   $_SESSION["bank"] = $_SESSION["bank"] - $_SESSION["bet"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! So basically what this does is if the session bank isnt set it will say 100, but if it is set it will use the set value instead? I'm new to sessions, but thanks for the answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You should fill the `$_SESSION['bank']` value when creating the game, so it will be available all the time. Then you can do whatever you want with it when the user does an action.

Also, you hardcoded the bank value in your session bank calculation function. Maybe you should think about setting the bank value dynamically in another function? That gives you the option to change the start amount per game.